# VBA Excel - looping through ListView Controls

Tags: excel, vba, listview

I have 4 ListViews on the `UserForm`. Is it possible to check which `ListView` is active/selected as on the code below?

```
Private Sub CommandButton8_Click()
    For i = 1 To 4
        If me."ListView" & i) is selected Then
            MsgBox me("ListView" & i ).Name
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

It is not working with `ListView.SelectedItem`. I don't actually understand why? Even if `ListView` is not selected, `MsgBox` pops up first `ListView` item as `SelectedItem`.

```
For i = 1 To 4
    If Me("ListView" & i).SelectedItem > 0 Then
        MsgBox "listview" & i & " selected item is " & Me("ListView" & i).SelectedItem
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

First, when the data is loaded onto a listview control, the first item is automatically selected.  So, to avoid this from happening, set the Selected property for the first item to False after you've added the data.  For example...

```
Me.ListView1.ListItems(1).Selected = False
```

or

```
Me.Controls("ListView" & i).ListItems(1).Selected = False
```

Then you can use the following code to loop through each listview control, and then for each one loop through each item to check which one is selected...

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 4
        
        Dim lv As ListView
        Set lv = Me.Controls("ListView" & i)
        
        With lv
            Dim j As Long
            For j = 1 To .ListItems.Count
                If .ListItems(j).Selected Then
                    MsgBox lv.Name & " - " & .ListItems(j).Text
                    Exit Sub 'optional
                End If
            Next j
        End With
        
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

If you can have more than one item selected, and you want to display the name of each one, remove `Exit Sub` from the code.

Comment: After adding `.ListItems(j).Selected = False` in the loop it works great! Thank you @Domenic!

Comment: You're very welcome, cheers!